# Aligning trees built with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, trees

I want to align some trees I am creating.  I want the root node of all the trees to be on the same line.  Currently for each tree I create, the root node of each subsequent tree is on a line after the bottom of the previous tree. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In a very simple manner, you can specify the position of the root in the picture. Look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down,
  every node/.style={fill=red!30,rounded corners},
  edge from parent/.style={red,thick,draw}]
\node at (0,0) {root}
 child {node {left}}
 child {node {right}
 child {node {child}}
 child {node {child}}
};

\node at (4,0) {root}
 child {node {left}}
 child {node {right}
 child {node {child}}
 child {node {child}}
};

\node at (8,0) {root}
 child {node {left}}
 child {node {right}
 child {node {child}}
 child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This will be graphically:

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: [edge from parent fork down,every node/.style=fill=red!30,rounded corners}, edge from parent/.style={red,thick,draw}]

Comment: Now, I do now have nice straight lines as shown.  ALso, how can I get it to look more like a typical binary tree?  Also, the top two level of my trees, the nodes are black.

Comment: Happy that it works also to you. To have the picture more similar to a binary tree you just need to remove the general options in [ ] after the opening of the `tikzpicture`. You can also refer to the pgfmanual page 114 (version October 25, 2010).

Comment: I change the "header" inffo to this:

Comment: [edge from parent fork down, every node/.style=red!80, rounded corners, edge from parent/.style={red!80,thick,draw}]

Comment: Now, I do not have any borders on the node.  How can I now add circle - in red -  as borders

Comment: Ok just change your "header" into: `[ every node/.style={red!80, rounded corners,draw}, edge from parent/.style={red!80,thick,draw}]`

Comment: Ah,one more thing.   If I add only one node, it adds it in a straight vertical position.  Can I make it add to the left or right?  Like a binary tree, depending on the key.

Comment: @HaroldRosenberger Use the `[missing]` key on a child node.  See [How do I make an unbalanced binary tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47469/2693). You may also want to check out `tikz-qtree` (see my answer there) if you are drawing trees a lot; its syntax is much more compact.

Comment: I'm new to latex.  where/how do I specify the [missing] key?

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I see just add another node.

Comment: \node at (0,0)[rectangle,draw] {13}
 child{node[rectangle,draw]{7} child{node[rectangle,draw]{3}} child{node[rectangle,draw]{9}}} child{node[rectangle,draw]{16} child{node[rectangle,draw]{14  15}} child{node[rectangle,draw]{20  21}} }
 ;

Comment: for the above code, the 14/15 node and the 9 node overlay each other.  I do not know why.

Comment: Here's another example.  Nodes 9 and 15 overlap on the printed page.

Comment: [ every node/.style={blue!80, rounded corners,draw}, edge from parent/.style={blue!80,thick,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm}]

Comment: @HaroldRosenberger: Please clean up by removing the comments after this discussion. Comments are only for adding some valuable remark to an answer. Feel free to edit your question for adding information, or to post your own answer, or if it's derived from Claudio's solution, make an edit suggestion regarding his answer to extend it. But please delete those many comments, otherwise a mod may do it and you might keep some code though.