# How to draw the following figure using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning trees built with tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51084/aligning-trees-built-with-tikzpicture)

Is it possible to draw the following figure using TikZ?
[image]

It know how to draw simple tree diagrams using TikZ.
But this is little bit trickier for me.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But, it would be best if you show what you have tried and detail exactly you are having an issue with.  Ideal would be if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the specific problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: The `xypic` package also provides an easy way to draw these diagrams.

Comment: `pb-diagram` might work here

Comment: Please don't downvote further than -1. For the TeX.SX community, it's already a good indicator that this is an ill-posed question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too low-level, maybe:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=-2em]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[anchor=mid,inner sep=1pt]

\path (0,0) node{id} ++(1,0) node{*} ++(1,0) node{id};

\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
\path (0,0) node(F){$F$} ++(1,0) node{*} ++(1,0) node{id};
\path (F) ++ (0,1) node(id){id};
\draw (F) -- (id);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\path (0,0) node(T){$T$} ++(1,0) node{*} ++(1,0) node{id};
\path (T) ++ (0,1) node(F2){$F$} ++ (0,1) node(id2){id};
\draw (T) -- (F2) -- (id2);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\path (0,0) node(T2){$T$} ++(1,0) node{*} ++(1,0) node(F3){$F$};
\path (T2) ++ (0,1) node(F4){$F$} ++ (0,1) node(id3){id};
\draw (T2) -- (F4) -- (id3);
\path (F3) ++ (0,1) node(id4){id};
\draw (F3) -- (id4);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\path (1,0) node(T3){$T$} +(-1,1) node(T4){$T$} +(0,1) node(star){*} +(1,1) node(F5){$F$};
\path (T4) ++ (0,1) node(F6){$F$} ++ (0,1) node(id5){id};
\draw (T3) -- (T4) -- (F6) -- (id5);
\path (F5) ++ (0,1) node(id6){id};
\draw (T3) -- (F5) -- (id6);
\draw (T3) -- (star);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=7.5cm]
\path (1,0) node(E){$E$} ++(0,1) node(T5){$T$} +(-1,1) node(T6){$T$} +(0,1) node(star2){*} +(1,1) node(F7){$F$};
\path (T6) ++ (0,1) node(F8){$F$} ++ (0,1) node(id7){id};
\draw (T5) -- (T6) -- (F8) -- (id7);
\path (F7) ++ (0,1) node(id8){id};
\draw (T5) -- (F7) -- (id8);
\draw (E) -- (T5) -- (star2);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]