# using macros in tikz/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am trying to plot a family of hyperbolas and don't want to repeat the function definition every time. So for example I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
        \draw plot ({exp(\x)+exp(-\x)}, {exp(\x)-exp(-\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But now I want to put the point in a function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
        \def\hyper#1#2#3{({#1*exp(#3)+#2*exp(-#3)}, {#1*exp(#3)-#2*exp(-#3)})}
        \draw plot \hyper{1}{1}{\x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But then I get

> ! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this plotting
>   data.

I there an easy way to use such predefined macro as a point? Or is it not possible with `plot`?

I have seen [Problem using macros to define tree substructures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59694/problem-using-macros-to-define-tree-substructures) and [Forcing tikz/pgf to expand macros within commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18315/forcing-tikz-pgf-to-expand-macros-within-commands) as well as [pgf macro that returns a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20078/pgf-macro-that-returns-a-node) and [Programming in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19715/programming-in-tikz/19722) but I still don't understand what can be done when.

Any pointers to enlightening parts of the `TikZ/PGF` manual are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\draw plot` expects the x and y coordinates to be separated by a comma, but the way your function is set up now, it only sees one chunk of stuff (not correct LaTeX terminology).

One way to get around this is to put the `\draw plot` into the macro as well. You can make the macro accept an optional argument that is passed to the `draw` command, so you'll be able to alter the appearance of individual plots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
        \newcommand\hyper[4][]{\draw [#1] plot ({#2*exp(#4)+#3*exp(-#4)}, {#2*exp(#4)-#3*exp(-#4)})}
         \hyper[red]{1}{1}{\x};
         \hyper[blue]{0.5}{0.5}{\x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Instead of using the `\draw plot` functionality, you may want to take a look at PGFPlots, which makes it easier to create plots and add axes and legends etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\hyper[4][]{\addplot [#1] ({#2*exp(#4)+#3*exp(-#4)}, {#2*exp(#4)-#3*exp(-#4)});}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
         \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, smooth, axis lines=middle]
         \foreach \n in {0.25,0.5,...,2}{
            \hyper[domain=-1.5/\n:1.5/\n] {\n}{\n}{x}
         }
         \hyper[domain=-3:3, thick, red]{0.75}{0.75}{x}
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One disadvantage is, that I have to do this for every variant in which I use the function, e.g. `\newcommand\hyperline[6]{\draw ({#1*exp(#3)+#2*exp(-#3)}, {#1*exp(#3)-#2*exp(-#3)}) -- ({#4*exp(#6)+#5*exp(-#6)}, {#4*exp(#6)-#5*exp(-#6)})}`. But as I could replace the other occurrence with `[mark=*]`, this solution is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

TikZ/PGF uses its own parser. Here, you may define separately each coordinate (`\hyperx` and `\hypery`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
        \def\hyperx#1#2#3{#1*exp(#3)+#2*exp(-#3)}
        \def\hypery#1#2#3{#1*exp(#3)-#2*exp(-#3)}
        \draw plot ({\hyperx{1}{1}{\x}},{\hypery{1}{1}{\x}});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good idea for even longer formulas, but here it is not that much of a simplification.

Comment: @canaaerus: This is the only way to be able to use several `plot`s into a single `\draw`...

Answer (score 3):

Here an answer with tkz-fct and gnuplot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=6,xstep=1,
            ymin=-5,ymax=5,ystep=1]
\tkzAxeXY
\foreach \a in {0.25,0.5,...,2}{%
  \def\b{-\a}    
  \tkzFctPar[color=red,
             samples=200,
             domain=-1.5/\a:1.5/\a]{\a*exp(t)-\b*exp(-t)}{\a*exp(t)+\b*exp(-t)}}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]