# Expand macro at call site only

Tags: macros, tikz-qtree

I want to draw a tree where each edge has a certain weight visualized through both the line width as well as a label on the edge. Using TikZ, this is pretty easy:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        clabel/.style = { fill=white, circle, inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize},
    ]
    \Tree [.O
        \edge [line width = 2] node [clabel] {2}; L
        \edge [line width = 4] node [clabel] {4}; R
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since the tree I want to draw is rather large, I want to factor out the edge code, i.e. I would like to have a macro like

```
\def\edgeweight#1{\edge [line width = #1] node [clabel] {#1}; }
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX complains about the `\edge` command when I call this macro which I assume is because it appears outside of the `\Tree` command. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to the preamble fixes the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@@children\@@children
\def\@@children{\futurelet\my@next\my@@children}
\def\my@@children{%
\ifx\my@next\edgeweight\else
\expandafter\@gobble
\fi
\expandafter\old@@children}
\makeatother
```

---

This solution is due to David Carlisle and is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58987/47097). Congrats to the guy who wrote the related questions detector, this took me straight to the right place!