# How to make binary search trees in an easy and straight forward way?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to have this tree in LaTeX [image] and I found this helpful response on [this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47483/148199) but I easily got lost with all the brackets that are going on and I now have this [image]

Which is achieved by the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
     blank/.style={draw=none},
     edge from parent/.style=
     {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
     level distance=1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\Tree
[.51     
    [.12 ]
    [.87  
    \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{};
    \edge[.52
    \edge[]; {83}
     \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{};
    ]
    [.40
             \edge[]; {20}
             \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{};
         ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know that someone can easily fix all these brackets for me but I would appreciate another method that is easier, much more, so that I can also do the rest of the trees that I want to make on my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would simplify tree layout as follows:

[image]

and in drawing use package `forest`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow=south,
    circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt,
    s sep=7mm
        }
[51
    [12
        [1]
        [43
            [36]
        ]
    ]
    [87
        [52
            [83]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
considering [caverac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/152462/caverac) comment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow=south,
    circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt,
    s sep=3mm
        }
[51
    [12
        [1]
        [43
            [36]
            [,no edge, draw=none]
        ]
    ]
    [87
        [52
            [,no edge, draw=none]
            [83] 
        ]
        [,no edge, draw=none]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In above MWE you can nodes options `no edge, draw=none` can replace with shorter `phantom` (@ Arne, thank you for remind me on this).

Comment: In a binary search tree, the notions of `left child` and `right child` are fundamental, and they kind of disappeared in your implementation. I never used `forest` before but I think it is possible to make that explicit, would you be so kind and add a correction to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @caverac, this option is now added.

Comment: The solution in the addedndum is much much easier to implement and to read compared to what i had. Thanks a lot (+1).

Comment: Indeed the easiest syntax !

Comment: the `phantom` option build in makes `,no edge, draw=none` superfluous.

Comment: @Arne, you are right. With option `phantom` can be replaced `no edge, draw=none`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution using `tikz`, as an example consider the following tree

[image]

To create this code I used

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {minimum width = 2em, draw, circle},
  ]
  \node {51}
  child {node {12}}
  child {node {87}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this representation, it is very clear that both `12` and `87` are children of `57`. If you want to grow the tree, just keep adding children

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {minimum width = 2em, draw, circle},
  level/.style = {sibling distance = 30mm/#1}
  ]
  \node {51}
  child {node {12} 
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {43}
               child {node {36}}
               child {edge from parent[draw = none]}
              }
        }
  child {node {87}
         child {node {52}
                child {edge from parent[draw = none]}
                child {node {83}}
               }
         child {edge from parent[draw = none]}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%level distance=5mm,
level 1/.style={level distance=10mm,sibling distance=24mm},
level 2/.style={level distance=10mm,sibling distance=16mm},
level 3/.style={level distance=10mm,sibling distance=16mm},
font=\scriptsize,inner sep=2pt,every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=3ex}]

\node {51} % root
child {node {12} % first level
        child {node{1}} % 2sd level
        child {node{43} 
            child {node{36}} % 3rd level
            child[missing]
        }
    edge from parent }
child   {node {87} % first level
            child {node {52} % 2sd level
                child[missing] % 3rd level
                child {node{83}}
            }
            child[missing] 
        } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```