# How to draw simple two classification chart in LaTex?

Tags: diagrams, trees

I need to draw following chart in latex format. Currently i put it as image. Need some expert help to do it simplest way.

[image]

-------updated -----------------------------
According to given link in comment i will create tree like this,how i can format that text like given image and put two , trees side by side in same reference?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node {Cryptography}
    child {node {cryptos}
      child {node {hidden}}
    }
    child {node {graphia}
    child {node {writing}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/how-to-make-a-3-level-deep-tree-with-tikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use TikZ, but this will work and it uses no extra package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \Large Cryptography&\qquad&\Large Stenography\\[1ex]
    \Large$\swarrow\qquad\searrow$&&\Large$\swarrow\qquad\searrow$\\[1ex]
    \textit{cryptos}\qquad\textit{graphia}&&\textit{steganos}\qquad\textit{graphia}\\[1ex]
    \Large$\downarrow$\qquad\qquad$\downarrow$&&\Large$\downarrow$\qquad\qquad$\downarrow$\\[1ex]
    hidden\qquad writing&&covered\qquad writing
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your answer is working as i expected. :) thank you , but can i increase the horinzontal gap between two trees ,it looks like two closer each otheir ?

Comment: Sure. For instance, at the fifth line of my code, add another `\qquad` after the one that it's already there.

Comment: grate , it is simple and working. thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `font` key to set the font style and size.

Here's a solution using `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        ->,
        font = \Large,
        level distance = 1.5cm,
        level 1/.style={
            font = \normalfont\sl,
            sibling distance = 3cm
        },
        level 2/.style = {
            font = \normalfont\large,
            sibling distance = 1.5cm
        }
    ]
    \node {Cryptography}
        child {node {cryptos}
            child {node {hidden}}
        }
        child {node {graphia}
            child {node {writing}}
        };
    \node[xshift = 5cm] {Steganography}
        child {node {steganos}
            child {node {covered}}
        }
        child {node {graphia}
            child {node {writing}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tree]