# How to draw a game tree with LaTex especially with information set?

Tags: game-tree, istgame

I am in a trouble to create a game tree like this one.
Could you please help me work it out? I will be very thankful!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: You should look at the [forest](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/how-to-make-a-3-level-deep-tree-with-tikz can help as a starting point

Comment: thank you for all the comments

Answer (score 3):

As @jlab said, you can just use the [forest](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package to model the tree structure. After this is done you just have to draw a path between the according lines for dashes nodes and add the notes for the description to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % styling options
        [
        every path/.style={thick},
        round node/.style={fill=black,circle,draw,inner sep=1.5},
        level distance=15mm,
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=35mm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm},
        ]
        
        % general tree structure
        \node[round node] (level1) {}
        child {node[round node] (level2) {}
            child {node[round node] (level3) {}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$1$}] {} edge from parent node[left] {$a_1$}}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$0$}] {} edge from parent node[right] {$a_2$}}
                edge from parent node[above left] {$s_1$}
            }
            child {node[round node] (level32) {}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$0$}] {} edge from parent node[left] {$a_1$}}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$1$}] {} edge from parent node[right] {$a_2$}}
                edge from parent node[above right] {$s_2$}
            }
            edge from parent node[left] {$t_1$}
        }
        child {node[round node] {}
            child {node[round node] (level33) {}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$1$}] {} edge from parent node[left] {$a_1$}}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$0$}] {} edge from parent node[right] {$a_2$}}
                edge from parent node[above left] {$s_1$}
            }
            child {node[round node] (level34) {}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$0$}] {} edge from parent node[left] {$a_1$}}
                child {node[round node,label=below:{$1$}] (lowright) {} edge from parent node[right] {$a_2$}}
                edge from parent node[above right] {$s_2$}
            }
            edge from parent node[right] {$t_2$}
        };
        
        % annotations to the right
        \coordinate (legendX) at ($(lowright)+(1.5,0)$);
        \node at (legendX|-level1) {Nature};
        \node at (legendX|-level2) {Sender};
        \node at (legendX|-level3) {Receiver};
        \node at (legendX) {Payoff};
        
        % dashed lines
        \path[draw, dashed, bend left, gray] (level3) to (level33);
        \path[draw, dashed, bend right, gray] (level32) to (level34);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I am really thankful

Comment: if I want to add another number below, where should I modify? I tried but it does not work.